# Website rank based on keyword search

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-adsense, google-ads, sem

is there any possibility to get a list of website that have very good rank based on a keyword search.

For example keyword is **cat food** ,
 then i have to  get list the top 100 website that have high rank in this keyword in the country **UK** .

Comment: yes, you should check out keyword position tracking tools, such as Sistrix, SEMrush and others. There are many that do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like SEMrush to get data like this. But I'm not familiar enough with the tool to tell you how accurate the data is.

Google doesn't allow robots to crawl its search engine to determine its rankings. As a result, the most accurate method that I know of to find out the top 100 sites for a result is to simply scroll to each page in Google's search results manually.

Automating this process might not be possible, as Google will use a captcha service to determine if you're a human or a robot. And crawling the results may be disabled by Google's servers.